# Can I transfer and deposit my ethereum in etherdelta wallet?

Tags: etherdelta

Can I transfer and deposit my Ethereum in [myetherwallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/)?

I have not been able to move my Ethereum from the transfer mode to my etherwallet in etherdelta. Please help..

[image]

Comment: etherdelta is a decentralized exchange. They do not hold your funds. Try installing metamask and import your account to metamask, then go to etherdelta you should have your funds

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.
already deposited 0.995 eth to your etherdelta account from your wallet.
use the chat area to fix any issue